# $||AB||_{op} \leq ||A||_{op} ||B||_{op}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove the following?
$||AB||_{op} \leq ||A||_{op} ||B||_{op}$

---

Research effort:
$||A||_{op} = \sup_{||v||=1}||Av||$.
So it's my task to show that:
$$  \sup_{||v||=1}||Av|| \cdot  \sup_{||v||=1}||Av||  \geq \sup_{||v||=1}||ABv||$$ 
So it's enough to prove that
$$ ||Av|| \cdot ||Bw|| \geq ||ABu|| $$ for any vectors $u,v,w \in S$.
I thought it would be helpful to write 
$$Av = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle a^i,v\rangle e^i$$
Where $e^i$ are the mostly used unit vectors, and $a^i$ is a row out of $A$. I got stuck with writing this for $||ABv||$ though.

Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *false* that for *any* vectors $u,v,w$, $\|ABu\| \le \|Av\| \|Bw\|$. For example, what if $ABu$ were nonzero but $v$ was in the null space of $A$?

Instead, you can solve this problem by applying the following property a few times: If $\|A\|$ is the operator norm of $A$, then for any $v$, $\|Av\| \le \|A\| \|v\|$.

Comment: I tried what you suggested before, but didn't succeed. Thank you for your answer anyhow.

Comment: What if I said that you should write $ABu$ as $A(Bu)$?

Comment: Well... I see it. It's pretty easy I admit. Thank you.